# Access node env variable in javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am setting `env` variable in `start` command in package json as below

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.config.dev.js --env.mode=dev --port 4200"
  },
```

and then I am trying to access this `env` variable using `process`, but apparently its not working.

**scripts.js**

```
   let url = process.env.mode == 'dev' ? 'local-url' : 'url';
```

I am getting below error:

```
scripts.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I have tried adding `.eslintrc.json` file with below content, but it did not work out

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

I am not sure if this is right way to identify the environment and access env variable in javascript files, please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the webpack configuration file?

Comment: @tmhao2005
Hi, please refer to this question, I have pasted my config file content here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989697/how-to-access-webpack-config-variable-in-other-js-file

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create .env file to store your variables in it.

Then use the npm package dotenv
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Basically in your top file that is the entry point add:

```
// commmon modules
require('dotenv').config()

// ES modules
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config()
```

After that you will have access to all the variables using process.env

Comment: I tried installing `dotenv` package and running my app, I am getting below error:
`ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
[config] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\.....\node_modules\dotenv\lib'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `webpack.DefinePlugin()` to export your environment variable into your build and make its value available to your client-side scripts.

In your Webpack config file, you should have a `plugins` array (if you don't, simply add it to the config object). Add the following as an item in the `plugins` array:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.mode': JSON.stringify(process.env.mode)
});
```

When Webpack builds your client script, it will now replace all occurrences of `process.env.mode` with the actual value so that it works as expected when running the script in a client.

If you need more environment variables or any other build-time constants available to the client runtime, simply add them to the object you pass to the `DefinePlugin` constructor. Just make sure you name them properly to avoid collisions with variables you may declare in your client scripts, as this could mess things up badly.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: but my problem is, I am not able to use `process` variable itself in js flie.

Comment: @AshokDamani This will solve that for your use-case. `process` itself can't be available in your client scripts because the client scripts run in a completely different environment. At build-time, you have to export the things you need. That's what the code I provided does.

Comment: its not working for me, I have added DefinePlugin as you mentioned, and trying to access env variable using process in my client js file, but getting same error: `process is not defined`

Comment: seems DefinePlugin is not injecting variable for me.

Comment: @AshokDamani Can you edit the question and add the change you made? It should work so there's obviously something missing, but I need to see it to be able to help.